# Not able to get a desired date time format rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I want a date time format which looks like this:- Tuesday, 27th December 2011 at 3:30 pm.

I made changed in the en.yml file to look like this

```
time:
    format:
        short_ref: "%A, %d %b at %I"
```

When I try to run the app I get this error : 18n::MissingTranslationData in Home#index

translation missing: en.time.formats.long

What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `strftime` function in ruby. That gives you a lot of flexibility in manipulating the date formats of ruby.

You can also try something similar to this :

```
date = Time.now
date.strftime("%d %b %Y at %I:%M:%S %p")
```

This will return the date in this format :

```
27 Dec 2011 at 05:47:20 PM
```

Learn more about the `strftime` function in the [Ruby API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)